# VSCode - turn off ommit type annotations warnings

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

How can I turn off this warnings?

[image]

I like the Dart strict type variables, I don't know why it is bad now...

Comment: It is properly this Linter rule https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html which can be disabled by https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#disabling-individual-rules

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from a lint:

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html

You can enable/disable lints by editing your `analysis_options.yaml` file.

> I like the Dart strict type variables, I don't know why it is bad now...

To be clear, the hint isn't encouraging you to do anything that changes the type. Replacing the left-most `UserService` with `var` or `final` will not change the type of the variable, as it will just be *inferred* instead. You don't need to type it explicitly if it's just the same as the expression on the right hand side.